# react-native unable to resolve module 'events'

Tags: xcode, mongodb, react-native

I have created an empty project with the following command:

```
react-native init demoProject
```

after installing

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

then I have installed mongoDB with the following command:

```
npm install mongodb --save
```

In the `package.json` file I have the following:

```
"dependencies": {
"events": "^1.1.1",
"mongodb": "^2.2.31",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.47.1"
```

},

In the `index.ios.js` file I am trying to import the mongodb as the following:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

After building the project in Xcode I have this error:

```
bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `events` from `/Users/rzilahi/work/demo01/node_modules/mongodb/lib/apm.js`: Module does not exist in the module map
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Mongodb library is for nodejs, not react native. In nodejs you have some library already present, but not present in react native. Actually if you want to install this library on react native you will have to install a lot of libraries like event / util / crypto. For example crypto library isn't accepted by react native you will need to install [react-native-crypto](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-crypto) . Also i don't think it's the job of your mobile app to interract directly with mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you importing MongoClient to index.ios.js ? It shouldn't be imported in the index or any other file of your app. Database queries should be done in a webservice. So in your app, you can use `fetch` to retrieve data from a webservice and render that with a `FlatList` or component of choice. You can create a `NodeJS` project on port 1337 (example port) and run the Node Server. In that Node Project you need to import MongoClient and query the DB for data and use `res.send` or `res.json` to send the data back as a response. So if you're able to access your webservice at http://localhost:1337/getdata , you're all set.

You may need to use your actual IP address of the computer in `fetch`, like:

```
fetchData(){
    fetch('http://192.168.0.4:1337/getdata')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({data: responseJson})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);   
    });
}
```

And your node server would look something like:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');

var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;  

var app = express();

//create the Posts Schema or import it.

app.get("/getdata", function(req, res){

    Posts.find({}, function(e,doc){
        if(doc==null){
            res.send("NO POSTS");
        }
        else{
            res.json(doc);
        }
    });

});

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 1337));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Server started on port: " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: hello! thank you for ur answer. :) So the getdata is basically the endpoint for the mongodb itself? Thanks for clarifying that i dont need to import the mongo client to index js also! :)

Comment: Updated the answer. Check the node part for clarification. Learn about mongoose and queries and it should be easy for you. Does that answer your query?

Comment: i did add the mongoose package, and requiring in the js file as you did in ur example. Still. when i am building the app, it fals, with the following error: 

`error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `util` from `/Users/rzilahi/work/demo01/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js`

i did my research on google, but couldnt solve the error. :( any idea?

Comment: Remove mongodb as dependency and uninstall it from the project. You do not need mongoose in the app. It should be called in the webservice, as I stated earlier. Create a separate project for node server / web service and add the mongoose dependency there. Test the paths over there. Build again.

Comment: okay, i am one step forward i guess. :) this separate project is a bit confusing. i have created it now, and also created a github repo which includes both projects. one of them is the `react-native` project, de other one is supposed to be the `server`. now, the only thing i want to achieve, is to show a query result in the app, which comes from the mongoDb. this is where i am at the moment: 
https://github.com/zilahir/react-app-demo
please give me hints, how can i move forward. :) thank you!

Comment: Where did you create the Posts Schema? You need to create the Schema to use `Posts` to query mongodb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152287/discussion-between-richard-zilahi-and-somename).